# ARM ubuntu fails to get certain packages

Tags: apt, chroot, arm

I have ARM ubuntu running under a chroot and everything seems to be set up and working well, however when I go to install certain packages I end up with failing to fetch errors, this does not happen for all. 
For example when I try to install xfce4 I get:

```
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/f/fuse/libfuse2_2.9.2-4ubuntu2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd-daemon0_204-0ubuntu15_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/a/apparmor/libapparmor1_2.8.0-0ubuntu30_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd-login0_204-0ubuntu15_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/d/dbus/dbus_1.6.12-0ubuntu8_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd-services_204-0ubuntu15_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_204-0ubuntu15_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/f/fuse/fuse_2.9.2-4ubuntu2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/w/wayland/libwayland-client0_1.1.0-2ubuntu2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/w/wayland/libwayland-cursor0_1.1.0-2ubuntu2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dri_9.2.1-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/w/wayland/libwayland-server0_1.1.0-2ubuntu2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm1_9.2.1-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/m/mesa/libegl1-mesa_9.2.1-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/m/mesa/libopenvg1-mesa_9.2.1-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/m/mesa/libegl1-mesa-drivers_9.2.1-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/d/dbus/dbus-x11_1.6.12-0ubuntu8_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libgomp1_4.8.1-10ubuntu7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base1.0/libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0_1.2.0-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/s/systemd/libgudev-1.0-0_204-0ubuntu15_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/u/upower/libupower-glib1_0.9.22-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/cpp-4.8_4.8.1-10ubuntu7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/cpp_4.8.1-2ubuntu2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/d/desktop-file-utils/desktop-file-utils_0.21-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/libh/libhybris/libandroid-properties1_0.1.0+git20130606+c5d897a-0ubuntu32_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/libh/libhybris/libhybris-common1_0.1.0+git20130606+c5d897a-0ubuntu32_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/libh/libhybris/libhardware2_0.1.0+git20130606+c5d897a-0ubuntu32_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/u/upower/upower_0.9.22-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/x/x11-apps/x11-apps_7.7+1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-common_1.14.3-3ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xorg-core_1.14.3-3ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/x/xorg/xserver-xorg-video-all_7.7+1ubuntu5_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/x/xorg/xserver-xorg-input-all_7.7+1ubuntu5_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/x/xorg/xserver-xorg_7.7+1ubuntu5_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/x/xorg/xorg_7.7+1ubuntu5_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

about 12MB of the packages fail

Comment: Any idea about this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

Which version of Ubuntu are you running? End-of-life ports have their repos renamed. I found a discussion [here](http://talk.radxa.com/topic/313/solved-issue-with-ports-ubuntu-com) that explains the solution:

1) Back up /etc/apt/sources.list

2) Assuming you use Raring (13.04), replace the contents with the following:

> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main universe
>   restricted multiverse
>  deb-src
>   http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main universe restricted
>   multiverse
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main
>   universe restricted multiverse
>  deb-src
>   http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main universe
>   restricted multiverse
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main
>   universe restricted multiverse
>  deb-src
>   http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main universe
>   restricted multiverse
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main
>   restricted universe multiverse
>  deb-src
>   http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main
>   restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-proposed main
>   restricted universe multiverse
>  deb-src
>   http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-proposed main restricted
>   universe multiverse

3) Run `apt-get update`, and it should be working again.

Worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Based upon your output shown above, it typically is best to re-run `sudo apt-get update` and then attempt the install once again.  The cached view of what ports.ubuntu.com *should* look like to make package downloads isn't matching what is really there for packages.

Comment: Also, make sure your date/time on your host is correct.  Drift may cause add messages that suggest that packages are not valid in the pool.