# apt source lists non-existent version of .deb package

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, apache2, arm

I've `apt update`'d from my `sources.list`, but the install fails because it apparently links to a non-existent package.

```
$ apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
     2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/main armhf Packages
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main armhf Packages
     2.4.18-2ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial/main armhf Packages


$ sudo apt-get install apache2 -y
...
After this operation, 4,889 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main armhf apache2-bin armhf 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
Ign:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main armhf apache2-utils armhf 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
Ign:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main armhf apache2-data all 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
Ign:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main armhf apache2 armhf 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main armhf apache2-bin armhf 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main armhf apache2-utils armhf 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main armhf apache2-data all 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main armhf apache2 armhf 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

- http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/a/apache2/ lists `apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.3_armhf.deb` but not `apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1_armhf.deb` (3.3 vs. 3.1). Is this an issue with the repo or my config?
- For what it's worth, I didn't think the issue was [a PPA-wide 404](https://askubuntu.com/q/65911/49899) as  the repo exists but is missing the package. (I'm only using default ports.ubuntu.com sources (armhf), and [xenial is not EOL](https://askubuntu.com/q/417466/49899), right? Unless just `xenial-security` has moved to [old-releases](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/49899): `old-releases.ports.ubuntu.com`?)

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't figure out why my `apt-get cache` listed `2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1` when only `...ubuntu3.3` was available, but I did find that `...ubuntu3` (no decimal) installed just fine if I specified that version (or removed the other deb sources)